# Error creating bean with name 'blSearchService' when adding AuthorizeNet to Broadleaf

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, authorize.net, broadleaf-commerce

When I follow the steps to add AuthorizeNet to my Broadleaf Commerce site. I receive the following exception when executing mvn tomcat7:run:

**EDIT:** I am using Authorize 1.9.2, Broadleaf Authorize 2.6.0 GA, and Broadleaf DEMO 5.0.5 GA. Here is the stack trace. It was a little too long so I trimmed it. Here is the full stack trace - http://pastebin.com/kWK0BN4r

```
[ERROR] 10:10:56 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSearchService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSolrIndexService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSolrIndexService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSearchService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSolrIndexService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blSolrIndexService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:

  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.solrConfiguration; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blCatalogSolrConfiguration' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)

    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)
```

Comment: What version of AuthorizeNet, what version of Broadleaf and what is the entire stack trace?

Comment: I am using AUthorizeNet 1.9.2 Broadleaf Authorize 2.6.0 and Broadleaf Demo 5.0.5